# Android Camera in Portrait on SurfaceView

Tags: android

I tried several things to try to get the camera preview to show up in portrait on a `SurfaceView`.  Nothing worked.  I am testing on a Droid that has 2.0.1.  I tried:

1) forcing the layout to be portrait by: `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

2) using

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
parameters.setRotation(90);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Is there something else I can try?  If this a bug in Android or the phone how can I make sure that this is the case so that I have proof to inform the client?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: Have a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259299/force-a-camera-to-always-open-in-portrait-mode-in-android/10259572#10259572

Comment: can any one help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379130/how-to-set-camera-image-orientation

Answer (score 65):

As of API lvl 8, this is available:

public final void setDisplayOrientation (int degrees)

i.e. with portait in the manifest:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

Comment: I have done this but the byte[] I am getting still gives me a landscape photo.

Comment: Set mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); camera view Ok, But video result not the same Camera View , It not rotation 90. why?

Comment: Hey, you can use param.setRotation(..) method for this. I am still trying to figure out how it works. It's awesome!

Answer (score 12):

i have a working solution for portrait mode working in 2.1 (tested on Desire) maybe less.

Activity screen orientation is set to portrait.
(android:screenOrientation="portrait")

the camera parameters:

Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

```
 p.set("jpeg-quality", 100);
 p.set("orientation", "landscape");
 p.set("rotation", 90);
 p.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
 p.setPreviewSize(h, w);// here w h are reversed
 mCamera.setParameters(p);
```

and the image will be portrait.

SurfaceHolder you use for camera must be at a size compatible with phone preview size
usualy screen resolution.

Funny on Desire 2.2 is not working...
Here is the fix:

```
   At surfaceCreated(..) or when you have this line
camera = Camera.open();
       add
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);//only 2.2>

Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    p.set("jpeg-quality", 100);
p.setRotation(90);
p.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
p.setPreviewSize(h, w);
camera.setParameters(p);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try this (good for 2.2 or below).  Here I rotate the image before saving it to sd card. But it is only for portrait mode. If you had to make it for both mode then you should check camera orientation and put some check before capturing image.

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      FileOutputStream outStream = null;
      try {
        imageFilePath = getFilename();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        // Getting width & height of the given image.
        if (bmp != null){
           int w = bmp.getWidth();
           int h = bmp.getHeight();
           // Setting post rotate to 90
           Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
           mtx.postRotate(90);
           // Rotating Bitmap
           Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           rotatedBMP.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
           byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray(); 
           outStream = new FileOutputStream
                              (String.format(imageFilePath,System.currentTimeMillis()));
           outStream.write(byteArray);
           outStream.close();
        } else {
           outStream = new FileOutputStream
                              (String.format(imageFilePath,System.currentTimeMillis()));
           outStream.write(data);
           outStream.close();           
        }       

        preview.camera.startPreview();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this on many current devices, including the G1 and Droid. Take a look at the relevant bug report here:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193

Also see a comment from one of the Android engineers (Dave) here:

- http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/24dfa452ffc0e049

Answer (score 0):

The link Roman gave of the issue thread has a workable solution that I'm using now.

Find it here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193#c26

Answer (score 0):

There is no need you have to set any parameters for the orientation until you need to do that explicitly. By Default, it supports this facility. In my case, i have a Activity and above that activity i have a camera view, so i didn't set any orientation for the camera properties, instead for the activity i set the orientation as portrait in the Manifest file. now the app looks and works good. Might be helpful for some one..

Thanks.