# Abnormal picture on Camera API android

Tags: android, api, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Camera in Portrait on SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543059/android-camera-in-portrait-on-surfaceview)

I don't know how to fix it. I need help from someone , i am new for android . this is the first post. I am sorry for my poor english ,  Best regards

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private static final String TAG = "CAMERA_TUTORIAL";
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean previewRunning;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
                surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
                surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
                surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        if (camera != null){
            Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            camera.setParameters(params);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (previewRunning) {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
            {
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            }

       try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewRunning = false;
        camera.release();
    }
}
```

This is my image . i have got it on HTC inspire

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP0eH.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell me what is exactly your problem is?

Comment: Thank you so much, i am glad when i see you are interest in it. now i can solved it . Like this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543059/android-camera-in-portrait-on-surfaceview .  now i am adding Zoom-in and Zoom-out . ^ ^